# Centering a multi-layered canvas wrapped around by a div

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to have multiple HTML5 canvases to be stacked on top of each other which would allow me to have multiple layers when rendering with JS. Not only that, but also have the multi-layered canvas be centered on the document horizontally and vertically.

This would be only possible, however, if all of the canvases are transparent. To make the canvases still be visible and not the same color as the document body (which I've set to black in my case), I had the idea of wrapping a div around the canvases and setting the div's color. This would make the canvases "be" a different color than the body while still retaining the transparent property.

However, I can't find exactly the right CSS properties to set for the div and canvases in order to get what I'd like. The common end result is usually the div having the width of the entire document and 0 height.

The bare-bone structure of my HTML document is

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body
            {
                background : black;
                ...?

            }
            div
            {
                background : white;
                ...?
            }
            canvas
            {
                ...?
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <canvas></canvas>
            <canvas></canvas>
            <canvas></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any solution that'd let me have the canvases be stacked and centered on screen with them not being the same color as the body would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've realized I'm an idiot and I over complicated the situation a bit. All I really had to do was just change the background color of the bottom canvas and that's it. Uploaded the question anyways for future references.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body
            {
                background : black;
                overflow   : hidden;
                margin     : 0px;

            }
            canvas
            {
                display    : block;
                position   : absolute;
                margin     : auto;
                padding    : 0;
                top        : 0;
                bottom     : 0;
                left       : 0;
                right      : 0;
            }
            #bgcanvas
            {
                background : white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="bgcanvas"></canvas>
        <canvas></canvas>
        <canvas></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```